# "Javascript, The Good Parts": Railroad Diagrams

Tags: javascript

I'm reading "Javascript, The Good Parts" by Douglas Crockford, and having a difficulty understanding the use of all the railroad diagrams. He also doesn't elaborate much on this. He just says the following (on pg. 21):

> The rules for interpreting these diagrams are simple:
>
> - You start on the left edge and follow the tracks to the right edge.
> - As you go, you will encounter literals in ovals, and rules or descriptions in rectangles.
> - Any sequence that can be made by following the tracks is legal.
> - Any sequence that cannot be made by following the tracks is not legal.
> - Railroad diagrams with one bar at each end allow whitespace to be inserted between any pair of tokens. Railroad diagrams with two bars at each end do not.

I am aware that this book is considered to be fundamental read for anyone who's really serious about Javascript, and I would very much like to understand the concepts he's addressing. But something just isn't clicking about the whole railroad diagram thing.

Could anyone explain his use of the railroad diagrams? Examples would be great.

Comment: [This](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Syntax_diagram) might be a good start...

Comment: Have you read any references on [syntax diagrams](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Syntax_diagram)?

Comment: Thanks guys for responding! +1

Comment: Try http://stackoverflow.com/q/15917859/926460

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Railroad diagrams (Syntax diagrams, http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Syntax_diagram) are a graphical way to explain a grammar.  If all you want to do is understand a railroad diagram, understand that you start at the left, and follow the line (track).  And when you encounter a symbol/name, you go follow that track, until it is done, and then come back where you left off.

Also, reading about BNF and EBNF (Extended? Backus-Naur Formalism, http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Backus%E2%80%93Naur_Form) which is a formal way of describing a language grammar, using a set of productions, or rewrite rules.  BNF/EBNF work the same as railroad diagrams, but using symbolic notation, the ::= production symbol, and a more formal/mathematical way to document a grammar.

Answer (score 7):

This [IBM page](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/wmqfte/v7r0/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.wmqfte.doc/railroad_diagrams.htm) probably has the simplest explanation.

The [Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Syntax_diagram) offers more info in how to construct them.

Answer (score 4):

I am also reading this book. It takes me a long time, but finally understand Railroad Diagrams.

First, as @ChuckCottrill mentioned, you should have a basic acknowledge about **Syntax Diagrams** and **BNF/EBNF**. But after reading that, it still confused me until I compare three graphs of different situation:

**zero or more, zero or one, one or more**

To understand their differences (as the following picture shows), the point is
*"You start on the left edge and follow the tracks to the right edge."*
So imagine you are the train, you just turn right, cannot turn left.

[image]

the above picture created by https://www.bottlecaps.de/rr/
In the "Edit Grammar" tab, input the following grammar:

```
zeroormore ::= element*
zeroorone ::= element?
oneormore ::= element+
```